# Runtime Exception while instantiating Server class for rmiregistry

Tags: java, classpath, rmi

I tried the same program on my Ubuntu VM and the program even yielded the correct output but on Windows its giving a weird runtime exception:

```
e:\java\rmi final>javac *.java
e:\java\rmi final>rmic ServerImplement
e:\java\rmi final>rmiregistry 20361  
<< BLANK , fine >>
e:\java\rmi final>java ServerMain 20361  
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread;   
nested exception is:     
     java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments;   
nested exception is:  

        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerImplement_Stub
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:396)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)  
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)  
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)  

        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)  
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(Unknown Source)  
        at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.rebind(Unknown Source)
        at ServerMain.main(ServerMain.java:9)  
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is:

        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerImplement_Stub
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:386)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:250)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ServerImplement_Stub

        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:434)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
        at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1575)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1496)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1732)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1329)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:351)
        ... 12 more
```

Here is my `ServerMain` class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.rmi.*;

class ServerMain
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   try {
        Naming.rebind("//localhost:"+args[0]+"/TestClass",new ServerImplement());
        System.out.println("TestClass is uploaded on the server. on port "+args[0]);

    }  
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       //System.out.println("FAILED. ERROR: ");
        e.printStackTrace();
   } 
 }
}
```

On Ubuntu:

```
machine@ubuntu:~/rmi final$java ServerMain 20361
TestClass is uploaded on the server. on port 20361
```

Comment: A successful bind does not mean `"TestClass is uploaded on the server."`. There is no upload involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. The -cp switch wasnt helping either.. 
Added a ";" after "." in my CLASSPATH environment variable. Silly problem.. x-(

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to specify `-cp` switch. JVM really does not know where your stubs are.

Comment: Looks to me that the code is in the same directory as the execution attempt, so no classpath should be needed there, right?

Comment: tried with -cp . and -classpath . bt to no success. It still shows the same error. :-/